# az cli: How to retrieve key vault secret value alone, with no double quotes?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, azure-secrets

Using `az cli` command of `az keyvault secret show --name $SecretName --vault-name $KeyVaultName --query value)` returns the secret with double quotes.

This causes my subsequent REST call to fail.

How do I return the secret value only, no double quotes?

I also tried the `--outputs tsv` flag, but this returns a bunch of values. Per the docs, the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the behavior. When I used `az keyvault secret show --name $SecretName --vault-name $KeyVaultName --query value -o tsv`, I only get the unquoted secret value.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this. @GauravMantri comment to add **-o tsv** is a simple/good solution. Another option is to use the tool **jq**. Output your data as JSON and process the desired keys. **jq** is what many developers use in command scripts.

Answer (score 20):

This was the exact question I had and JayakrishnaGunnam-MT's answer was helpful.

I feel like putting it all together was the one missing piece that I needed.

So, the below statement is what gave me the exact result I needed--and I think is the most direct solution to the original question.

```
az keyvault secret show --name $SecretName --vault-name $KeyVaultName --query value -o tsv
```

1. `az keyvault secret show --name $SecretName --vault-name $KeyVaultName` get the secret
2. `--query value` query for only the value of the secret
3. `-o tsv` format that query result to its raw value (no double quotes)

If I omit #2, I get more than just the secret value.

If I omit #3, I get just the secret value but with double quotes.

If I have that full statement, I get just the secret value and without double quotes--which is the result I need.

Answer (score 13):

@Gaurav Mantri thank you for your answer in the comment section converting it to answer

you can try this command to get the secret value without double quotes.

`az keyvault secret show --name secretname --vault-name keyvaultname -o tsv`

Answer (score 0):

Friendly FYI: [How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=examples%2Cbash) has Bash, PowerShell and CMD examples to return values without quotes when using the Azure CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - looks correct.  However, in order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid link-rot), we prefer answers that provide at least a summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information.